# Regular expression to match a URL pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract the following part from a url using regular expression but its not finding any match . Can anyone please take a look what i am doing wrong ?

This is the url:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/700943129497635499/sent/?invite_code=ba8f1ef48e1747199003308cdc92bbb9&sender=773000860950082435&sfo=1

I want to extract :

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/700943129497635499

My code is :

```
url="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/700943129497635499/sent/?invite_code=ba8f1ef48e1747199003308cdc92bbb9&sender=773000860950082435&sfo=1";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https://www\\.pinterest\\.com/pin/.*/", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
url = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(url);
```

It says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far`

Comment: This regex matches what you are asking, assuming that the only variable in the url is the number after "pin"
`(https:\/\/www\.pinterest\.com\/pin\/)(\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

- You should invoke `matcher.find()` before using `matcher.group()`.
- The regex with `.*` causes to include the match `/sent/` part. You can use `https:\\/\\/www.pinterest.com\\/pin\\/\\w+` instead. `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` or you can use `\d+` to match only number values
- Other issue is with `matcher.group(1)` part. There is no capture group in the regex `(...)`. So if you use `group(1)` then you'll get an exception. If you use the regex with parentheses `(https:\\/\\/www.pinterest.com\\/pin\\/\\w+)` then you can use `matcher.group(1)`

---

```
String url = "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/700943129497635499/sent/?invite_code=ba8f1ef48e1747199003308cdc92bbb9&sender=773000860950082435&sfo=1";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https:\\/\\/www.pinterest.com\\/pin\\/\\w+");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
    url = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Output:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/700943129497635499
```